# Nexus 7 Error: Failed to mount /cache

Tags: bootloader, cache, bootloader-lock

I had a problem with my Nexus 7 (2013, 2nd gen) tablet.

I restarted my tablet and when it was rebooting again, it showed "Google" logo and then stood there.
I wait it (around 20 minutes) but it did not do anything else.

## Trying factory reset... [failed]

I have check many videos that suggesting apply a hard reset or factory reset, so I tried to do this.
Once in `Recovery mode`, I notice that some error messages appear at bottom of screen, they are:

```
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Failed closing /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/misc (I/O error)
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
```

Then I selected `wipe data/factory reset` option and execute it. It started to formatting `/data`but then similar errores were flushed (here I copy log):

```
-- Wiping data...
Formatting data...
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
Formatting cache...
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
Data wipe complete.
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /cache/recovery/last_install
E:Failed closing /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/misc (I/O error)
E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)
```

Here I show an image of recovery error messages[image: image of recovery error messages]

## Trying unlocking device... [failed]

Some pages and forums suggest to flash and install another ROM, I have selected `Cyanogenmod` and following steps shown in[Cyanogen wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_flo). The first step is unlocking device, this process starts formatting `/data` and then formatting '/cache', but again it cannot be mounted.

---

Finally...
How can I fix these issue?

Comment: Have you tried [Wugfresh Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)? Most of time Nexus devices can get fixed easily with the toolkit.

Comment: The problem is the cache partition is an invalid format. Select _"wipe cache partition"_ from the menu to fix it.

Comment: @bain, Thank you for your comment. After select `Wipe cache partition`, it throws the same error message `E: failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)` and as your can think `cache` partition cannot be wiped or formatted if it is not mounted before.
Do you have another idea?

Comment: I had the same issue but I pressed  the Power Button along with Volume down solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into `fastboot` and run `fastboot format cache` and then `fastboot erase cache`.

Comment: It does not work, format neve ends.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when running the commands?

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a very similar issue but in my case the "Formatting ..." step was not followed by a failed to mount message. In my opinion there is a hardware issue with your unit -- if the format fails such that the resulting partition can not be mounted, there's not much that can be done except attempt a warranty repair.

Comment: Thank you, before this error I replace the touchscreen, then I used it only some days and then this issue appear, Do you think that some hardware connection could be failing?, In this case, I should open it again and that everything is properly plugged.

Comment: *Possibly* -- I would have thought that the storage in question was soldered to the logic board without a socket (it is according to the [iFixit teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+7+2nd+Generation+Teardown/16072)).

Comment: And if you reflash the phone through a Flash Tool?