# Can I flash Nexus 7 with Odin?

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-7

## Current status

### Device issue

I have a Asus Nexus 7, I can't flash anything with `fastboot`because all flash procedures I have read need to unlock (using `fastboot oem unlock`) or mount `/cache` partition and for some reason when I try something I get freezed mounting `/cache` partition.

More details about this please read: [Nexus 7 Error: Failed to mount /cache](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89892/nexus-7-error-failed-to-mount-cache), which still **UNSOLVED**.

### Asus support

I asked to Asus Support Service (in USA and Mexico) and they answer that this device do not have support.

## My claim

So I want to try to flash using a tool like Odin. Maybe it can solve my problem (now I have an expensive *paperweight*).

Comment: Odin is for Samsung devices. You would need a comparable tool from ASUS (I do not know if one exists).

Comment: With Odin, no its a different flashing protocol but it is a nexus so as long as the hardware is not fried you should be good to go. Google makes all the needed software for nexus's available. Are you getting those errors cannot mount /partion_whatever? your EMMC might be fried. With fastboot what have you tried? Is adb.exe and fastboot.exe installed on your computer? Open a administrator command prompt from your PC. Completely power down the device then enter the bootloader by press & hold the Power button + volume down button together. Then from prompt type fastboot devices what is returned?

Comment: @user981, Thank you for your reply.
I now understand that "Odin is for Samsung devices".

Comment: @BoLawson, Thank you for reply.
(1) I get many `E:failed to mount /cache (invalid argument)` messages. How can I confirm that EMMC is done.

Comment: First, can you get into the bootloader and get fastboot commands running? Because one way to test is to unlock bootloader and see how your device reports it. If it has hardware issue it will not change the reported state.

Comment: @BoLawson
(2) In a terminal when I execute `fastboot devices` I get `05861998 fastboot` (this number is the device serial number).
(3) If i try to execute `fastboot oem unlock` in terminal, it show `...` (three dots) as waiting confirmation of bootloader unlock in device screen. Then I select `yes`in screen and press `power` button, then immediately terminal shows `(bootloader) Unlocking bootloader...`and then `(bootloader) erasing userdata...` and still there.

Comment: Uh-oh if still erasing user data thats an issue bit i might have seen a fix. If it completed  though check to see if it unlocked first throw fastboot command: fastboot reboot-bootloader     check bottom left at locked state what does it report. Next fastboot command: fastboot oem device-info   what is returned?

Answer (score 0):

OEM device-info? I found plenty of confirmation of what I suspected which is a corrupted bootloader. Look at Google issue [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/yN85FEM8jTc), [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/nexus/8JPs4hll3Dk), and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2417097). OK what you need to do is.

1. Download a factory OTA for your device.[Here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/02/02/flash-all-the-things-lollipop-ota-update-zip-file-roundup/#download) is a collection of OTA's but verify md5 to be sure.
2. Take OTA for the OS you currently have get the upgrade. Based on your other post recovery picture it's KK 4.4.4 KTU84P to LR50
3. Sideload the next OTA with ADB command.

> adb sideload 0xxxa.signed-nakasi-version-from-version.0xxx9.zip

It should start to load once complete reboot. Don't worry with an official OTA your bootloader needs to be locked.

4. Repeat OTA sideload but this time from LR50 to LR51.

This should get you back up and running. If somethings off then the OTA should abort. If you need a debugging script refer to first here reference and check with with csm.hrm's example.

Comment: Unfortunately It does not work. :(
Once I select `apply update from ADB` option and execute `adb sideload 5189573323c8a232cbe42fc3413ce006c585c7cb.signed-razor-LRX22G-from-LRX22C.51895733.zip` in terminal, device shows these 3 messages: `E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)`, `E:failed to set up expected mounts for install; aborting` and `Installation aborted`.

Comment: Here you have an image of these messages: http://www.comunidad.escom.ipn.mx/ibuitron/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/photo_2015-09-02_00-27-04.jpg

Comment: Before giving up I would try to update in order from 4.4.4 KTU84P to LXR21P 5.0. The reason the corrupted bootloader is KTU84P. Also OTA should be done in order because they arereally patches to framework and so on

Comment: bad news!, I executed `adb sideload 5a0f7a47588c268c239e58cf568823c6637c5af1.signed-razor-LRX21P-from-KTU84P.5a0f7a47.zip` in terminal but it shows the same messages 3 messages: `E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)`, `E:failed to set up expected mounts for install; aborting and Installation aborted`.