# Nexus 7 (2013) stuck at Google's logo after downgrade to factory image 4.3 (JSS15Q)

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-7, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) shipped with Lollipop 5.1. I downloaded the 4.3 factory image from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images and flashed it on the device. But after reboot, it just stuck on the Google's logo screen. I tried to search the solution, but didn't find one.

Please help. Thanks.

---

Updated 1:
Just for test, I downloaded another several different factory images after that, which are 4.4, 4.4.4, 5.0 and 5.1. Finally, I found all images below 5.0 can't work on my device.

I flash the image just by running "flash-all.sh"

---

Updated 2:
I also noticed there're some errors in the recovery mode. Here's the screenshot
[image]

I discovered there's a similar question with me [Nexus 7 Error: Failed to mount /cache](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89892/nexus-7-error-failed-to-mount-cache). I tried with "fastboot format cache" and "fastboot erase cache", but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm experiencing an almost identical problem, except that now I can't even flash a 5.0 stock ROM (which worked fine last time I tried, around a year ago).

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find the solution. Instead I used another device eventually. I searched a lot on the internet, someone said it's the hardware's problem. But I can always flash back to it's original firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully resolve a very similar problem with my 2013 Nexus 7. However, I have not actually confirmed that it works with an Android 4.X stock ROM yet.

I discovered that my system default `fastboot` command (located at `~/bin/fastboot`) was a symlink pointing to an executable `fastboot-mac` from the CF-Auto-Root package. (I must have made this change a long time ago for some other purpose and forgotten about it.)

The solution was to change the symlink to point to the proper `fastboot` executable located in my `android-sdks` directory. I then flashed a 6.0.1 stock ROM (MOB30X specifically) using `flash-all.sh`, and after 10 minutes of the Marshmallow boot animation, it successfully booted into Android. (Flashing the same stock ROM using the same procedure had not worked previously.)

I have a bit of evidence that suggests that this change was actually important, in addition to the fact that it worked this time. In the previous flash attempts with the old `fastboot-mac` executable, the `flash-all.sh` log messages included the following:

```
erasing 'cache'... OKAY
rebooting...
```

However, they did not mention that the cache partition was actually rewritten at any point. The new `fastboot` includes the log messages:

```
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.026s]
sending 'cache' (10984 KB)...
OKAY [  0.375s]
writing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.466s]
rebooting...
```

which explicitly says that the cache has actually been rewritten.

Comment: Note: I had also previously used TWRP to change the `/cache` and `/data` partitions to use the `f2fs` filesystem instead of `ext4`, which seemed to get rid of some of the error messages in your question. However, I don't think this actually helped, because I attempted multiple unsuccessful flashes after this change.

Comment: After 10+ unsuccessful flashes and 1 successful flash, I'm too concerned about being left with an unusable tablet to try again with a 4.X stock ROM. But if you try this, please comment to let me know how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Boot to recovery.

Backup everything you need using MTP Usb connection.

Wipe system, data, cache, and dalvik.

Flash the image again.

Comment: Yes, I just used flash-all script within the factory image package and flashed the whole images.